# App installation failed: illegal Bundle identifier

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I'm working on WatchKit app extension and when I run my project in the physical device I got this alert message:

[image]

However, I checked Info.plist and my bundle identifier is

> com.myname.myappname

and my bundle identifier of my WatchKit extension is

> com.myname.myappname.extension

Isn't this just right? I cleaned and built again and again., but it just won't work.

How can I build that in physical device?

Comment: what is your bundle identifier, check if there is some additional . over their

Comment: Yeah i checked clearly no additional dot is there.

Answer (score 0):

check again,

Do something like this if there is something different,

My app identifier is - **com.WTS.Siri-Extension**

My extension identifier is - **com.WTS.Siri-Extension.Siri**

My extension Name is - ***Siri***

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if there are trailing spaces on either of your bundle identifiers.

Comment: Yeah i checked clearly no additional trailing spaces is there.

Answer (score -1):

Followed the below process. And it is worked for me.

You have to be careful when changing the bundle identifiers, here's how they should be set (you need can change each identifier in the Info.plist for the iPhone app, for the Watchkit Extension and for the Watchkit App):

iPhone Application Info.plist:

Set any bundle identifier as you like (the "Bundle identifier" property).

Example:

Bundle identifier: com.fruitcompany.orange
WatchKit App Info.plist

The bundle identifier here must be prefixed with the identifier of the iPhone application, like this(example):

Bundle identifier: com.fruitcompany.orange.watchkit
You also need to change the WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier which must match with the iPhone application bundle identifier, like this:

WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier: com.fruitcompany.orange
Watchkit Extension Info.plist:

The bundle identifier here must be prefixed with the identifier of the iPhone application, like this(example):

Bundle identifier: com.fruitcompany.orange.watchkit.extension
You also need to set the WKAppBundleIdentifier under the NSExtension attribute.

WKAppBundleIdentifier

The WKAppBundleIdentifier identifier must match with the WatchKit app bundle identifier like this:

WKAppBundleIdentifier: com.fruitcompany.orange.watchkit